# Sub-context menu for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I want to create sub-contextmenu for Filters in my datagrid. How can I do that? Here is my code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGridSuppliers" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsReadOnly="True" >
        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Create Supplier" Click="btnCreateSupplier_Click" />
                <MenuItem Header="Edit Supplier" Click="btnEditSupplier_Click" />  
                <MenuItem Header="Filters" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create *nested sub menuItems inside Filters*, that's all what you want:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="Create Supplier" Click="btnCreateSupplier_Click"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Edit Supplier" Click="btnEditSupplier_Click"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Filters">
        <MenuItem Header="Sub Filter 1"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Sub Filter 2"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Sub Filter 3"/>
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```